# .htaccess, placed inside subdirectory, to point paths to said subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

**Edit: CONFIRMED NOT POSSIBLE**

I have a static HTML site where all references are absolute, based on the document root being `/`

**eg.:**

- `<img src="/images/myimg.jpg>`
- `<link href="/styles/main.css">`
- and so on...

For testing purposes, I need to be able to put the site inside of a sub-directory and point all paths to that directory.

**ie.,** the paths need to effectively be this:

- `<img src="/sites/myvsite.com/images/myimg.jpg>`
- `<link href="/sites/myvsite.com/styles/main.css">`
- and so on...

The catch is that my `.htaccess` file needs to be in `/sites/myvsite.com` to because I can't modify files in the document root.

Is this possible with `mod_rewrite` or some other `.htaccess` facility?

Comment: You face the problem that your `.htaccess` style file won't be evaluated inside some arbitrary subdirectory, since the absolute references point somewhere else.

Comment: @arkascha: So is this just not possible at all?

Comment: No, if I got your description right. The issue is that you use absolute path (something that rarely is a good idea...). This means the request asks for `/images/myimg.jpg` or whatever. So a `.htaccess` style somewhere file inside `/sites/myvsite.com` is not considered at all. There is no requests to that location.